# question about dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, when solving $Ax=b$ numerically in projection method, we approximate the exact solution $x^*$ by $y$ in the subspace $K$ which has the dimension $m$.

my textbook said $m$ constrains must be imposed to extract such an approximation, a typical way is select $V\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ which is column independent and require that $V’y=0$

this confused me, shouldn’t it be $n-m$ restrictions? for example, $n=3$, and I want to approximate the solution in $K=\{z=0\}$, so $m=1$, we need 2 more conditions about the $x$-axis and $y$-axis.

Comment: Do you mean $K=\{ (x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3 | z=0 \}$? If that's the case then $m=2$, not $1$ as you thought.

Comment: @BigbearZzz thanks, I understand what's wrong.